# SHOUTcast Admin Login with php

Tags: php, authentication, shoutcast

What is the link for remote login in shoutcast administrator. I think it's

www.ip:port/admin.cgi?pass=*Password*      But i'm not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the URL is http://server:port/admin.cgi, but it looks like they are using basic authentication, not form based authentication.

Read more about basic auth here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication